# Creating a method which specifically calculates the average of the users entered values

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse

I am making a program which allows the user to look at student's grades, find the average, find the highest grade, the lowest etc. For one of the methods I have, it checks for the average of the values that the user entered. I tried to do this but to no avail. Here is the specific code:

```
public static void classAvg(int numOfKids) {

        int average = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < numOfKids; i++) {
            average += studentGrade[i];
        }

        average = (average/numOfKids) * 100;

        System.out.println("The average of the class will be " + average + "%");

    }
```

For some better context, here is the rest of the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StudentGradeArray {

    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    static String[] studentName;
    static String letterGrade = " ";

    static int[] studentGrade;
    static int gradeMax = 0;
    static int gradeMin = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println("How many students are you entering into the database?");
        int numOfKids = input.nextInt();

        studentGrade = new int[numOfKids];
        studentName = new String[numOfKids];

        for (int i = 0; i < numOfKids; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter the student's name:");
            studentName[i] = input.next();
            System.out.println("Enter " + studentName[i] + "'s grade");
            studentGrade[i] = input.nextInt();
        }

        do {    

            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Enter a number for the following options:");
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("1. Student's letter grade");
            System.out.println("2. Search for a student and their grade");
            System.out.println("3. The class average");
            System.out.println("4. The student with the highest grade");
            System.out.println("5. The student with the lowest grade");
            System.out.println("6. List of students that are failing");
            System.out.println("7. Quit the program");
            int options = input.nextInt();

            switch(options) {
            case 1:
                letterGrade(options); break;
            case 2:
                searchStudent(); break;
            case 3:
                classAvg(options); break;
            case 4:
                markHighest(options); break;
            case 5:
                markLowest(options); break;
            case 6:
                markFailing(options); break;
            case 7:
                return;
            default: 
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("Please enter a valid option.");
                System.out.println(""); break;

            } 

        } while (!input.equals(7));
        System.out.println("Program Terminated.");

    }

    public static void letterGrade(int numOfKids) {

        System.out.println("Enter a grade: A, B, C, D, F");
        letterGrade = input.next();

        if (letterGrade.equalsIgnoreCase("a")) {
            gradeMax = 100;
            gradeMin = 80;
        }
        if (letterGrade.equalsIgnoreCase("b")) {
            gradeMax = 79;
            gradeMin = 70;
        }
        if (letterGrade.equalsIgnoreCase("c")) {
            gradeMax = 69;
            gradeMin = 60;
        }
        if (letterGrade.equalsIgnoreCase("d")) {
            gradeMax = 59;
            gradeMin = 50;
        }
        if (letterGrade.equalsIgnoreCase("f")) {
            gradeMax = 49;
            gradeMin = 0;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < numOfKids; i++) {
            if (studentGrade[i] <= gradeMax && studentGrade[i] >= gradeMin) {
                System.out.println(studentName[i] + " has a " + letterGrade);
                System.out.println(letterGrade + " is equivalent to " + gradeMin + " - " + gradeMax + "%");
            }

        }

    }

    public static void searchStudent() {

    }

    public static void classAvg(int numOfKids) {

        int average = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < numOfKids; i++) {
            average += studentGrade[i];
        }

        average = (average/numOfKids) * 100;

        System.out.println("The average of the class will be " + average + "%");

    }

    public static void markHighest(int numOfKids) {

        int highestNum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < numOfKids; i++) {

            if (studentGrade[i] > highestNum) {
                highestNum = studentGrade[i];
            }

        }

        System.out.println("The highest mark in the class is " + highestNum + "%");

    }

    public static void markLowest(int numOfKids) {

        int lowestNum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < numOfKids; i++) {

            if (studentGrade[i] < lowestNum) {
                lowestNum = studentGrade[i];
            }

        }

        System.out.println("The highest mark in the class is " + lowestNum + "%");

    }

    public static void markFailing(int numOfKids) {

        for (int i = 0; i < numOfKids; i++) {
            if (studentGrade[i] < 50) {
                System.out.println(studentName[i] + " is failing with a mark of " + studentGrade[i] + "%");
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What are you doing? What do you expect to happen? What happens instead? Be precise. Give your inputs, expected output and actual output. "but to no avail" is a much too vague description of the problem.

Comment: Note: there is no reason for your method to take an argument: an array has a length attribute. And you're not passing the number of kids. You're passing the option chosend by the user. You really need to learn finding such bugs by yourself. Just printing the variable values would allow finding that. And using a debugger would even be easier.

Comment: In "average = (average/numOfKids) * 100;", why divide by 100?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the argument passed to the classAvg() is not the numOfKids (or size of array) but the option selected by the user from the menu. Trying passing 'numOfKids' instead of passing 'options' as an argument to the function

`case 3:
                classAvg(options); break;`

Better still use studentGrade.length instead of passing argument.

Answer (score 0):

```
case 3:
    classAvg(options); break;
```

You are passing in the options, but the method wants numOfKids. In this case options will always be 3. 
Try passing in numOfKids instead.

Another problem I see is that both average and numOfKids are integers, which causes chopping remainders and rounding to 0 if the denominator is greater. Perhaps change from

```
average = (average/numOfKids) * 100;
```

to

```
average = ((double) average)/ numOfKids * 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to create a class called Student, with properties name and grade. for more OOP design.

```
public class Student{
   int[] grades;
   String name;

   public Student(int[] grade, String name){
      this.grade = grade;
      this.name = name;
   }

   public double getAverage(){
     return (average/(double)numOfKids) * 100;
   }
   ...
}
```

And `average` is of type int and `numOfKids` too, so the division is not gonna be precise. try this `average = (average/(double)numOfKids) * 100`;